# sessionCreated is called before user is logged in

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring-security-3.2, Tomcat 7
I try to call `sessionCreated` method of `HttpSessionListener` after player is logged.
It seems that the problem appeared after updating spring version from v2 to v3.

Here is my Listener

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

public class DeactivateSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(DeactivateSessionListener.class);

    private static final String LOGIN_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME";


    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        if (isLogged()) {
            HttpSession session = event.getSession();
            session.setAttribute(LOGIN_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, AcegiUtils.getLogin());
            cashSessionId(session);
            addPlayerOnline(session);
        }
    }
public static boolean isLogged() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof String) {
            // anonymous user
            return false;
        } else if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
//          if (!((UserDetails) principal).isEnabled())
//              return false;

            // real user
            return true;
        } else {
            logger.warn("principal NOT String and NOT instanceof org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetails. i do not know what it means");
            return false;
        }
    }
.......
}
```

Here is my login form

```
<form method="POST" action="#{ownUrlController.https}#{ownUrlController.ownUrl}#{request.contextPath}/#{urlController.loginUrl}#auth-name" id="login_form">
            <label>Email</label>
            <p><input type="text" class="inpt" name="j_username" id="login" /></p>

            <label><h:outputText value="Login" escape="false"/></label>
            <p><input type="password" class="inpt"  name="j_password" id="pass" /></p>
            <div class="erroe-mess">
                <h:outputText value="#{localeController.locale.mainMsg.loginError}" rendered="#{param.error == 'true' and param.errorTry != 'true' and param.accountLocked != 'true'}" styleClass="error" escape="false"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{localeController.locale.mainMsg.loginBlockedError}" rendered="#{param.accountLocked == 'true'}" styleClass="error" escape="false"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{localeController.locale.mainMsg.loginTryError}" rendered="#{param.errorTry == 'true'}" styleClass="error" escape="false"/>   
            </div>
            <input name="token" value="#{multipleFormSubmitController.formToken}" type="hidden" />
            <p class="last"><input type="image" src="#{request.contextPath}/img/enter.png" onClick="login_volid()" value="#{localeController.locale.mainMsg.login}" title="#{localeController.locale.mainMsg.login}" alt="#{localeController.locale.mainMsg.login}" id="btn_login" /></p>

            <span class="reglink"><a href="#{ownUrlController.https}#{ownUrlController.ownUrl}#{request.contextPath}/#{urlController.registrationUrl}" class="registration-link"><h:outputText value="#{localeController.locale.mainMsg.registration}" escape="false"/></a></span>
            <span class="rememblink"><a href="#{request.contextPath}/#{urlController.forgotPasswordUrl}"><h:outputText value="#{localeController.locale.mainMsg.forgotPassword}" escape="false"/></a></span>
        </form>
```

And when I click Login, sessionCreated method is called, but method isLogged() returns false.

If I fogot something to post, point me, please.
Any ideas why listener is called before I log in with spring security?
I'll be very appriciated for any help.

Comment: What is the usecase for this listener (as I would argue you are doing things in the wrong place). There have been changes in how and where things are stored. Also there is no garantuee that only Spring Security will create a session (I would expect JSF also to do things in that area).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `HttpSessionListener` for this as there is no garantuee that Spring Security will intiate the session creation or maybe even worse it destroys and creates a session (depending on your session strategy).

Instead you should create an `ApplicationListener` which listens for `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` this event contains the `Authentication` which in turn contains details of the type `WebAuthenticationDetails` which in turn contains the id of the session.

If you want to cleanup based on the session id create a listener that listens to `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`s which are fired by the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` which I suggest you register.